# Do I have to wait with the domain unlocked after requesting an authorization code?

Tags: domains

So I have a domain name in a service that charges me 4 times the usual price for renewal. Everytime I try to transfer it they attempt to do something to prevent it. Now I requested an authorization code and they claim they have to "evaluate if they authorize it" and make me wait 3 days. Also, at the same time, they warn me that if I leave my domain unlocked (for the transfer) someone could steal my domain. My question is, do I have to leave the domain unlocked these 3 days, while I wait for their authorization code they are going to decide if I'm worth getting? Or can I lock it again?

The TLD is .com and the registrar is Network Solutions.

Comment: Leaving your domain unlocked for a few days is pretty unlikely to lead to it being stolen unless it is a really high ranking, very valuable domain

Answer (score 3):

Your question lacks useful details, starting with the domain name, or a least the TLD. And the registrar involved. Note that if you are attempting a transfer, the new/prospective registrar should be able to help you to make it succeed, so you need to contact it, not the old registrar.

If it is a gTLD, transfers are governed by ICANN rules that set among other things the limited list of reasons a registrar can deny a transfer.

Have a look at section 8 of https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en to start with.

If by lock you mean EPP status `clientTransferProhibited` (see https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en#clientTransferProhibited for details), then yes, you need to make sure your domain does NOT have this status in order for a transfer to proceed.

"someone could steal my domain." is kind of meaningless. A transfer can happen only if knowing the current `authInfo` of the domain, which the current registrar should give you. So until you get that code, you do not need to change the domain name status as you can't do anything yet. Once you get the code you can go to any registrar and attempt the transfer as soon as you remove the status (and the change is applied by current registrar).

If your name is not in a gTLD then you have less paved resources. You may want to contact the registry directly to try to resolve issues with registrar.

Now that you added the TLD and registrar in your question:

- certainly follow ICANN advices above to resolve the issue
- you can look in whois the current state of your domain, including EPP statuses ("locks")
- note the following in section 6 of above FAQ link: "Your registrar may allow you, via an online interface tool, to generate and manage your own AuthInfo code. If not, you will need to contact your registrar directly to obtain it. Your registrar must provide you with the AuthInfo code within five (5) calendar days of your request."; this is contractual, remind the registrar of his duties, and escalate with ICANN if you don't get the code in 5 days.
- make sure your domain is not close to expiring, otherwise you will have troubles (I recommend not to attempt transfer in the last month as a ballpark)

Comment: updated details. Considering they claim  the domain could be stolen, I dont want to mention it. Also by naming the registrar I didnt know if I was violating some term of use , it sounds like publicity or bad publicity in this case.

Comment: @Pablo A transfer can not happen without knowing the `authInfo`. Also even if a transfer starts, unbeknownst to you, the current registrar has 5 days to either allow or deny it (and it is allowed automatically if it does nothing) and every reputable registrar should contact its customer then to make sure it is aware of the transfer and hence have opportunity to refuse it (on the rare change the authInfo was guessed or retrieved somehow). What is more concerning here is that you have to wait to just get the `authInfo` from current registrars. See ICANN details, this must be below 5 days.